# How to cast a STRING to a GUID

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need cast a `String` to a `Guid`.

I am using this code but

```
string myUserIdContent = ((Label)row.FindControl("uxUserIdDisplayer")).Text;
Guid myGuidUserId = new Guid(myUserIdContent); // PROBLEM HERE
MembershipUser mySelectedUser = Membership.GetUser(myGuidUserId);
```

I receive this error

> Exception Details: System.FormatException: Unrecognized
>   Guid format.

What is the proper way to achieve the results?

Comment: Of course, you could correct the format...

Comment: What about using GuidConverter Class? Could you give me an example?

Comment: Please post the exact string you're using.

Comment: "9accaf71-fe30-48dd-b8a0-062459b4cdfc" string

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your error just by using the string you've provided. Set a breakpoint in your code and MAKE SURE that `myUserIdContent` is really set to what you think it is.

Comment: The string you're showing us **will** convert to a Guid just fine.... either you're not really getting that string, or something else fails...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Guid.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparse.aspx).

```
      string myUserIdContent = ((Label)row.FindControl("uxUserIdDisplayer")).Text;
      Guid myGuidUserId;
      if (Guid.TryParse(myUserIdContent, out myGuidUserId)
      {
          MembershipUser mySelectedUser = Membership.GetUser(myGuidUserId);
      }
      else
      {
          // throw exception and/or inform user
      }
```

Comment: Or, if you know the GUID is in a specific format: [`Guid.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparseexact.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

By the looks of that exception, your string isn't correctly formatted. Per MSDN:

> A string that contains a GUID in one of the following formats ("d" represents a hexadecimal digit whose case is ignored):
>
> 32 contiguous digits:
>
> `dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd`
>
> -or-
>
> Groups of 8, 4, 4, 4, and 12 digits with hyphens between the groups. The entire GUID can optionally be enclosed in matching braces or parentheses:
>
> `dddddddd-dddd-dddd-dddd-dddddddddddd`
>
> -or-
>
> `{dddddddd-dddd-dddd-dddd-dddddddddddd}`
>
> -or-
>
> `(dddddddd-dddd-dddd-dddd-dddddddddddd)`
>
> -or-
>
> Groups of 8, 4, and 4 digits, and a subset of eight groups of 2 digits, with each group prefixed by "0x" or "0X", and separated by commas. The entire GUID, as well as the subset, is enclosed in matching braces:
>
> `{0xdddddddd, 0xdddd, 0xdddd,{0xdd,0xdd,0xdd,0xdd,0xdd,0xdd,0xdd,0xdd}}`
>
> All braces, commas, and "0x" prefixes are required. All embedded spaces are ignored. All leading zeros in a group are ignored.
>
> The digits shown in a group are the maximum number of meaningful digits that can appear in that group. You can specify from 1 to the number of digits shown for a group. The specified digits are assumed to be the low-order digits of the group.

Comment: Guid is welle fomatted, I think is a problem with CAST. Maybe a Convert could solve it?

Comment: Please post the exact string you're using.

Comment: "9accaf71-fe30-48dd-b8a0-062459b4cdfc"